# k8s-visualizer can't read from apiserver

Tags: kubernetes

I've tried multiple forks of github.com/brendandburns/gcp-live-k8s-visualizer/issues/6. the current fork i'm trying to get working is (as mentioned by flx in another thread: https://github.com/0ortmann/k8s-visualizer ). I can get the interface to start up; but when teh script.js goes to `getJSON("/api..."....)` it tried to pull the /api URI from the current port (i.e.8001) for which it gets an unauthorized response? my apiserver is running on port 8080... any ideas?

Update: the "problem" appears to be related to (a) the fact that i'm making the browser http request from a remote host (i.e. i'm not going to http://localhost) and (b) the request filtering that the kubectl proxy is doing... adding the --disable-filter to the kubectl proxy command and doing a `curl <remotehostIP>:8001/api` at least gets me a response `<a href="/api/">Moved Permanently</a>` instead of unauthorized.  however, any `curl <remotehostIP>:8001/api/v1/pods` or similar gets an http 500 error... also the kubectl proxy command has 

`W1003 15:22:23.805574    8666 proxy.go:116] Request filter disabled, your proxy is vulnerable to XSRF attacks, pleas
e be cautious
Starting to serve on [::]:8001I1003 15:22:23.961109    8666 logs.go:41] http: proxy error: unsupported protocol sche
me ""
I1003 15:22:23.961311    8666 logs.go:41] http: proxy error: unsupported protocol scheme ""
I1003 15:22:23.961451    8666 logs.go:41] http: proxy error: unsupported protocol scheme ""
I1003 15:22:23.962003    8666 logs.go:41] http: proxy error: unsupported protocol scheme ""`

(unsupported protocol scheme messages repeat forever)...

Comment: Why was getJSON() trying to pull from 8001 instead of 8080?

Comment: That is my question, essentially; in script.js (the 'brains' behind k8s-visualizer) - there are calls to
`
    var req1 = $.getJSON("/api/v1/pods?labelSelector=" + label + "%3D" + value, function(data) {
    var req1 = $.getJSON("/api/v1/pods", function(data) {
    pods[dataKey] = data;
    $.each(data.items, function(key, val) {
        val.type = 'pod';
    });
`
which result in the browser making calls to http://<kubernetes-node>:8001/api/v1/pods, http://<kubernetes-node>:8001/api/v1/replicationcontrollers, etc...